# sharing session storage between multiple tabs in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to use data that is stored in session storage when I open a new tab in the browser. I know it is possible using local storage. But is there any better and efficient way to make it possible to use session storage in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, localStorage is the best tool to leverage what you want to accomplish. There isn't really an "angular" way of getting around this.

I would just save that data to localStorage and get it from the new tab.